# Deleting database rows in php & mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I need some advice on how to dynamically target the rows I wish to delete as currently I am manually having to alter my php script to delete rows but am a little stuck on where to go next.

so here is my index of items:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM items");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['added'] . $row['content']   . $row['id'];

  echo "<br>";

  echo "Mark as complete";

  echo "<br>";

  echo "<a href='delete.php'>Delete Item</a>";

  echo "<br>";

  echo "<a href='update.php'>Edit Item</a>";    

  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";     

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If I click on delete item it will only delete the one I have specified it to in my php here:

```
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM items WHERE id='14'");

mysqli_close($con);
```

Now I need to know how to tell the button to delete the item that the link is associated to as you can I have manually entered 14 so that will delete that one. But I need some instruction or advice on how to delete the row or item id of that row in the database.

My initial thoughts are I am going to need to pass some information about this row perhaps using $_GET?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the ID of the item to be deleted in the URL of `delete.php`. First add the ID to the url:

```
echo '<a href="delete.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">Delete Item</a>';
```

Then, in `delete.php` you need to use `$_GET` to get the paramater from the URL, and insert that into the delete query:

```
$id =$_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM items WHERE id='$id'");
```

However, you need to be aware that anyone can then come along, type in a URL in the format 'delete.php?id=' and it will delete that item. You should:

- Build in a confirmation method
- Look into using *prepared statements* to [prevent SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

Index of items page:

```
echo "<a href='delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Delete Item</a>";
```

Delete file:

```
$id = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['id']); // preventing sql injections
$con->query("DELETE FROM items WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: Glad I could help, remember to mark the question as complete :)

Comment: `real_escape_string` is not the best solution to prevent SQL injections

Comment: I am only learning at the moment so I am just trying to understand how and why things work so security is no issue for me at the moment.

Comment: Security should always be part of your learning. It is fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Secure solution:

```
    $id = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $sth = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM items WHERE id=?");
    $sth->bindParam(1, $id);
    $sth->execute();
```